# Cannot see the pylint report

Tags: pylint

This may be really basic but I cannot seem to be able to see the pylint report when I run it off my command line.

I went through the documentation and it seems the report publishing is labelled as off in my pylint options.

I then try to change it; however, there is some issue in changing the report display from no to yes as seen in the screenshot.

Would be very grateful if anyone could help me out with this.

I know it must be basic, but I am just getting started with programming.

Thank you so much.

example where I cannot see the report
[image]

error that pops up when I try changing the report settings
[image]

Comment: please post any code directly into your question, not as an image link.

Answer (score 12):

Based on your capture it appears you are missing the path to your file to enable the feature.
You can enable the Pylint report feature by using the following command `--reports=y`:

```
pylint --reports=y "pathToYourFile\file.py"
```

OR you can use the shorthand version using `-ry`:

```
pylint -ry "pathToYourFile\file.py"
```

Answer (score 1):

just as directory to your command line where your code is saved
eg:

1. Go to Desktop:

   `C:\Users\Sony>cd Desktop`
   `C:\Users\Sony\Desktop`
2. Save your code at dekstop.
3. Run your code using below style adding `-ry` at last:

   `C:\Users\Sony\Desktop > pylint sample.py -ry`

Hope it is helpful .